# Ellipse centre from two points and radius

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I might need some help on this problem. I searched online and didn’t find any way to solve it.

Given two points, I need to find the center of the two ellipses of given radius $rx, ry$ that intersects at those two points.

I know the two A and B point coordinates, as well as ellipses radius $rx$ and $ry$ (on $X-$axis and $Y-$ axis respectively).

Is there a way, from those $4$ variables, to calculate the center $C$ and $C'$ of each ellipse?

Here is a [little diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dj2w.png) I made to make things clearer.

[image]

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240031/solving-an-equation-for-an-ellipse) may be relevant.

Comment: This was definitely what I needed! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Scale the $y$-axis until $rx=ry$.
Fit two circles.
Undo the scaling.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I don’t understand how should I scale $y$-axis untir $rx = ry$.

If I take A 50, 50; B 90, 70; $rx = 40$ and $ry = 20$, how could I apply your solution?
Sorry, I’m not very good at this, so if you could try to keep it simple… Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you divide all coordinates by $r_x$ and $r_y$ (respectively), the ellipses become two unit circles, by two points. The centers are on the mediatrix of the two points, at a distance from the middle given by Pythagoras (if the distance between the points is $d, \sqrt{1-\dfrac{d^2}4}$). You can compute this by vector analysis.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I should divide $A_x$ and $B_x$ by $r_x$, Same for $A_y$ and $B_y$ by $r_y$. If I take $A = 50; 50$, $B = 90; 70$, $r_x = 40$ and $r_y = 20$, I find $A' = 1,25; 2,5$ and $B' = 2,25; 3,5$. Sorry but I don’t understand where this is going… Could you please elaborate?